# Get last application startup time VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net

I need my application display the time between the last time it was started and now. I tried using a Property in My.Settings, but that was ReadOnly, and couldn't be set on each startup, and user-scope isn't an option.

Comment: have you tried [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh(v=vs.80).aspx)?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're wanting to do this, but be sure you're aware of the full implications. If there's a single, shared location that stores this information, that is updated when *any* user uses the application, then logically *every* user has write access to that location. Among other things, this probably means that they can *forge* a different value for this property (since users, not applications, have permissions)

Comment: What do you mean by My.Settins is ReadOnly? I am using that in my application, it saves the last user input from a textbox, then show it whenever the application is started again.

Comment: @paynet - *user* settings can be updated. *application* settings are read only.

Comment: Damien, yes this is my intention, a computer-wide setting.